# Passing Paypal A PHP Variable as Amount

Tags: php, html, http, paypal, server

I have am making a website which does custom PC's and I have a form which they can choose their computer parts (different parts change the price).
After they have chosen their parts their is a script that adds it all up into a variable and sends it to page2.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('select').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#finalpriceexcvat").val(sum.toFixed(2));
});

$("#send").bind("click", function () {
    var url = "page2.html?value=" + encodeURIComponent($("#finalpriceexcvat").val());
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

It then tries to pass the variable to Paypal as the amount:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XVR95QDG6M53J">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="CiT Defender PC">
<input type="hidden" id="finalpaypal" name="amount" value="<?=$finalpriceexvat;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://make-my-pc.co.uk">
<input type="hidden" name="retun" value="http://make-my-pc.co.uk">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://make-my-pc.co.uk">
<input type="submit" class="read-more-btn4" value="Pay Now">
```

So when you press "Pay Now" it sends Paypal all the data including the "amount" which should contain the variable , however when I press the button it redirects to Paypal who give of the error:

> Error Detected
>   The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount.
>   .

So I assigned the "amount" an ID which was "finalpaypal" and then put the amount as a set value and then tried:

```
document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = finalpriceexvat;
```

But that doesn't seem to affect the price of the item.
Have I got something wrong?

Here is the output code:

```
<input id="finalpriceexcvat" name="finalpriceexcvat" disabled="" class="OBJ-4" maxlength="4" readonly="" autocomplete="on" style="position:absolute;left:760px;top:233px;width:136px;height:22px;readonly">
```

Comment: What is the actual value coming out of $finalpriceexvat?  It must not be a valid amount.  Provide us with the final result of what the code gives you (and you'll probably find the problem yourself.)

Comment: @AndrewAngell the output of $finalpriceexvat is definitely a valid amount , here is the form http://make-my-pc.co.uk/desktops/citdefender/

Comment: The form shown on that page does not look like the PayPal button you're showing above.  Where does the actual PayPal button form come into play so I can see it?  The error is very straight forward.  The amount must not be what you think it is by that point.

Comment: @AndrewAngell sorry managed to delete it :) it should be on the website now: http://make-my-pc.co.uk/desktops/citdefender

Comment: I'm still not seeing the actual PayPal form.  Just put it in your question please.

Comment: Sorry , the form and the paypal <form> are two different things , the paypal code with <form> on it is just the paypal button that sends all the values to paypal , if that was what you were looking for it is already on the question , it is the second code down .

Comment: Right, but you didn't put the ACTUAL html that is getting output by your code.  All you're showing here is the code that is generating the output.  I want to see the actual final output that is causing the problem.  $finalpriceexvat must not be a valid value like you think it is, and seeing the final output would allow us to see that.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I have added the code you requested

Comment: Somehow I am not being clear.  That is still not the line I'm looking for, and that line doesn't exist in the PayPal button code you supplied in the original question.  I'm talking about this line:  <input type="hidden" id="finalpaypal" name="amount" value="<?=$finalpriceexvat;?>">

Comment: Having pasted that here I can think of one thing that could be happening.  You're using shorthand echo for the value there.  If your server doesn't have that enabled in PHP, though, it wouldn't work, and then you would get no value, which would be invalid, and would trigger the error you are getting.  Again, though, we need to get a look at that line as it gets output without the PHP variable in it...but with the actual value.